# How to avoid mouse editing in gedit

Tags: 12.04, gedit

I am not used to edit text by mouse, I mean to use 'Drag-and-drop text editing'. In gedit 3.4.1: I am used to select a part of text by clicking and moving the mouse. But I wish to avoid moving the selected part of text by further clicking at it and moving the mouse. (I have not installed any gedit plug-in.) In Microsoft program options, there usually is a check box if to 'use the Drag-and-drop text editing'. I do not see such a setting in gedit. 
In the gedit, is it possible to **disable the drag-n-drop editing**? How? Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain a bit further what you mean by "edit text"? By default gEdit doesn't provide any additional mouse features, only through a plugin; do you have any mouse plugin installed?

Comment: In gedit 3.4.1: I am used to select a part of text by clicking and moving the mouse. But I wish to avoid moving the selected part of text by further clicking at it and moving the mouse. Thanks.

Comment: @TomasPeceny I still cannot really understand what you want - "shifting a selected text by mouse" ?? Do you want to have drag and drop for moving text?

Comment: @guntbert seems he wants to disable that behavior that he can drag-n-drop the text.

Comment: @Braiam, yes it seems so, but I am not certain, especially I cannot  see how *DragNDrop* would be a problem. I believe there is a language problem too and had those things rather clarified before trying to solve.

Comment: I really wish to **disable the drag-n-drop editing**. Is it possible? How? Thanks.